# how to use apply filter for Class?

Tags: filters, actions

Please do not remove the question saying that it's woocommerce.

In the code below there is  `$fields = wp_parse_args( $fields, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_fields', $default_fields, $this->id ) );`

so i believe that i can modify `$default_fields` by `add_filter`

```
/**
     * Output field name HTML
     *
     * Gateways which support tokenization do not require names - we don't want the data to post to the server.
     *
     * @since  2.6.0
     * @param  string $name Field name.
     * @return string
     */
    public function field_name( $name ) {
        return $this->supports( 'tokenization' ) ? '' : ' name="' . esc_attr( $this->id . '-' . $name ) . '" ';
    }

    /**
     * Outputs fields for entering credit card information.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    public function form() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );

        $fields = array();

        $cvc_field = '<p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc">' . esc_html__( 'Card code', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-cvc" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" maxlength="4" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'CVC', 'woocommerce' ) . '" ' . $this->field_name( 'card-cvc' ) . ' style="width:100px" />
        </p>';

        $default_fields = array(
            'card-number-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number">' . esc_html__( 'Card number', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;" ' . $this->field_name( 'card-number' ) . ' />
            </p>',
            'card-expiry-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry">' . esc_html__( 'Expiry (MM/YY)', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="cc-exp" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'MM / YY', 'woocommerce' ) . '" ' . $this->field_name( 'card-expiry' ) . ' />
            </p>',
        );

        if ( ! $this->supports( 'credit_card_form_cvc_on_saved_method' ) ) {
            $default_fields['card-cvc-field'] = $cvc_field;
        }

        $fields = wp_parse_args( $fields, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_fields', $default_fields, $this->id ) );
        ?>

        <fieldset id="wc-<?php echo esc_attr( $this->id ); ?>-cc-form" class='wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form'>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_start', $this->id ); ?>
            <?php
            foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                echo $field; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            }
            ?>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_end', $this->id ); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php

        if ( $this->supports( 'credit_card_form_cvc_on_saved_method' ) ) {
            echo '<fieldset>' . $cvc_field . '</fieldset>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        }
    }
}
```

But i am unable to do it. This is what i tried within the extended class

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_fields', 'ggowl_auth_creditform', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );`

```
public function ggowlwoo_field_name( $name ) {
        return ' name="' . esc_attr( $this->id . '-' . $name ) . '" ';
}

public function ggowl_auth_creditform($id){
    $id = $this->id;
    $default_fields = array(
                'card-number-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number">' . esc_html__( 'Card number', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull; &bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;" ' . $this->ggowlwoo_field_name( 'card-number' ) . ' />
                </p>',
                'card-expiry-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-first">
                        <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry">' . esc_html__( 'Expiry (MM/YY)', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="cc-exp" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'MM / YY', 'woocommerce' ) . '" ' . $this->ggowlwoo_field_name( 'card-expiry' ) . ' />
                </p>',
                '<p class="form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc">' . esc_html__( 'Card code', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-cvc" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="no" autocapitalize="no" spellcheck="no" type="tel" maxlength="4" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'CVC', 'woocommerce' ) . '" ' . $this->ggowlwoo_field_name( 'card-cvc' ) . ' style="width:100px" />
                </p>',
        );
    return $default_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a filter of a class's method you must use an array in the callback like this:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_fields', array( $this, 'ggowl_auth_creditform' ), 10, 1 );`. Of course that method must be public and either static, or the object must be instantiated.

Comment: Thank you. How did i miss that